# How to create and replace lines in a html file on iOS

Tags: html, ios, for-loop

I hava an html template file in my project, and I have an Array with items from 0 to 10.000. I like to create as many copys of `<img src="link" style="width:30.5mm;height:30.5mm;" class="addBorder"></img>`and replete `link` with the item at index of the array.

Eg: The array has 5 items

The html file should look like this after the for loop:

```
<html>
<style>
.addBorder {
    border: 29.5px solid #ffffff;
}
</style>
<body>
<table>
<tr>

<img src="file:///Users/David/Desktop/1_1STKK.png" style="width:30.5mm;height:30.5mm;" class="addBorder"></img>
<img src="file:///Users/David/Desktop/2_1STKK.png" style="width:30.5mm;height:30.5mm;" class="addBorder"></img>
<img src="file:///Users/David/Desktop/3_1STKK.png" style="width:30.5mm;height:30.5mm;" class="addBorder"></img>
<img src="file:///Users/David/Desktop/4_1STKK.png" style="width:30.5mm;height:30.5mm;" class="addBorder"></img>
<img src="file:///Users/David/Desktop/5_1STKK.png" style="width:30.5mm;height:30.5mm;" class="addBorder"></img>

<tr>
<table>
</body>
</html>
```

Ant this is the original html file template:

```
<html>
<style>
.addBorder {
    border: 29.5px solid #ffffff;
}
</style>
<body>
<table>
<tr>

<img src="link" style="width:30.5mm;height:30.5mm;" class="addBorder"></img>

<tr>
<table>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope that this is somehow possible.

**EDIT**

I fixed it my selfe, here is what I did:

```
for (int qr = 0; qr <= qrArray.count-1; qr++) {
                NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.png", [self documentPath], qrArray[qr]]];
                NSString *costumeLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src=\"%@\" style=\"width:30.5mm;height:30.5mm;\" class=\"addBorder\"></img>", url];
                [qrPDFArray addObject:costumeLink];
            }

            NSString*htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [qrPDFArray description]];
            htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@",\n    " withString:@"\n"];
            htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\"" withString:@"\""];
            htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"," withString:@""];
            htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"<" withString:@"<"];
            htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">\"" withString:@">"];
            htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(\n    " withString:@""];
            htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
            NSLog(@"%@", htmlString);
            NSString *tempFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"temp" ofType:@"html"];
            NSString* tempFileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:tempFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
            tempFileString = [tempFileString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"HERE" withString:htmlString];
```

Answer (score 1):

use NSString componentsSeparatedByString: method.

```
NSString *originalHTML = @"<table><tr><img link >aa</img><tr><table>";
NSArray *linkArray = @[@"aa",@"bb"]; //your links array
NSArray *allStrings = [originalHTML componentsSeparatedByString:@"<tr>"];
NSString *imgString = allStrings[1];
NSString *repeatedString=@"";
NSInteger i;
for(i=0;i<linkArray.count;i++){
    NSString *linkString = [imgString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"link" withString:linkArray[i]];
    repeatedString = [repeatedString stringByAppendingString:linkString];
}
NSString *finalHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<tr>%@<tr>%@",allStrings[0],repeatedString,allStrings[2]];

NSLog(@"%@",finalHTML);
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I think you misunderstand my question, I have an array with different filepaths inside. And I have an html file, where I have to add as many lines as items in the array. Then I have to replace the string link in the html file with e item at the item of the array, so eg. if the array has 5 items I have to add 5 times the line to the html file and replace the string "link" with the item at the array index. Sorry for the bad explanation, I am no native english speaker.